# How do I extract info from this table using python (ideally BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to gather information from this page: http://www.gatesfoundation.org/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database#q/page=2

Particularly, I'm trying to gather information from the table using BeautifulSoup. I have the following code:

```
pagelink = 'http://www.gatesfoundation.org/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database#q/page=2'
page = urllib2.urlopen(pagelink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
print soup
```

When I do this the contents of the table (within the "tablebody" tag) do not show up. Why is this? How would I go about extracting information from this table?

Comment: Well, I tried and with lxml tree I can get the info of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content you are looking for is **NOT from that URL**.

So basically when you **manually browse a page** in a modern web browser such as Chrome, **what you see** from that page, normally **is not entirely from the URL you requested**. The whole process would be: **get contents from the url you requested originally -> parse the content -> load CSS/JavaScript/images (from different urls most of the times) -> layout the page/make extra requests as per CSS/JavaScript askes**. It **might look like** all you got is solely from the URL you originally input in address bar, but **in reality the browser does tons of behind of the scenes stuff to fully render a web page for you**.

Now back to the page you are browsing, the content of that table **is actually populated by JavaScript**, which the browser **parses first and then makes extra requests to get the content and render into a full page**.

You can use tools such as `Fiddler` or `Charles` to **capture the whole process and analyze all traffic** to find out what happens behind the scene, in this case it's a `POST` request that getting content for that table:

```
POST http://www.gatesfoundation.org/services/gfo/search.ashx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.gatesfoundation.org
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 209
Accept: */*
Origin: http://www.gatesfoundation.org
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
Referer: http://www.gatesfoundation.org/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: gfo#lang=en; ASP.NET_SessionId=bdgjkbuyxxxcmfm40ejl2j1j; s_vnum=1641950372052%26vn%3D1; s_vi=[CS]v1|2C3C15910519363E-60000611E0003318[CE]; _vwo_uuid_v2=226610E3774AD35E29B29E7C20948349|f180edd6ae6830ab3de2432cd15b0bd4; __atuvc=3%7C2; __atuvs=58782b230157ce4a002; s_cc=true; s_nr=1484270424338; s_lv=1484270424339; s_lv_s=First%20Visit; s_invisit=true; gpv_p14=Awarded%20Grants; gpv_p19=How%20We%20Work; gpv_p21=no%20value; s_ppn=Awarded%20Grants; s_ppvl=Awarded%2520Grants%2C39%2C39%2C638%2C1366%2C638%2C1366%2C768%2C1%2CP; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_ppv=Awarded%2520Grants%2C67%2C67%2C638%2C1366%2C638%2C1366%2C768%2C1%2CP

{"freeTextQuery":"","fieldQueries":"(@gfomediatype==\"Grant\")","facetsToRender":["gfocategories","gfotopics","gfoyear","gforegions"],"page":"2","resultsPerPage":"12","sortBy":"gfodate","sortDirection":"desc"}
```

And **the response is JSON formatted**:

```
{
  "topResults": [],
  "results": [
    {
      "amount": 648140,
      "categories": [
        "Global Health"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-19T08:00:00",
      "description": "to validate biomarkers of growth stunting and environmental enteric dysfunction for the purpose of better understanding and diagnosing these related disease states",
      "grantee": "Stanford University",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "Stanford University",
      "topics": [
        "Enteric Diseases and Diarrhea"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1161946",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 550000,
      "categories": [
        "Global Development"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-15T08:00:00",
      "description": "to provide vital life-saving and sustaining support to populations most affected by conflict in Syria",
      "grantee": "World Vision",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "World Vision",
      "topics": [
        "Emergency Response"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1169747",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 3315475,
      "categories": [
        "Global Development"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-15T08:00:00",
      "description": "to fund activities focused on generating political will and building momentum for investment in nutrition at country level and supporting the development and implementation of the nutrition...",
      "grantee": "African Development Bank",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "African Development Bank",
      "topics": [
        "Nutrition"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1158425",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 500,
      "categories": [
        "Special Projects"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-14T08:00:00",
      "description": "to provide for general operating support",
      "grantee": "City Club",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "City Club",
      "topics": [
        "Community Grants"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1169105",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 78522,
      "categories": [
        "Global Health"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-12T08:00:00",
      "description": "to make the first description of specific histo-blood group antigens (HBGAs) in Zambian children and to assess their influence on immunogenicity of rotavirus vaccines.",
      "grantee": "CIDRZ",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "CIDRZ",
      "topics": [
        "Enteric Diseases and Diarrhea",
        "Vaccine Delivery",
        "Vaccine Development"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1162810",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 300000,
      "categories": [
        "US Program"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-09T08:00:00",
      "description": "to provide matching i3 funds with the goal of building professional capacity through effective professional development for teacher leaders and principals to improve college ready outcomes...",
      "grantee": "Leading Educators Inc",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "Leading Educators Inc",
      "topics": [
        "K-12 Education"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1169456",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 85330,
      "categories": [
        "Global Health"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-09T08:00:00",
      "description": "to collect and analyze existing data from multiple data streams from Asian and African sites to characterize early burden of rotavirus disease, which is less-well characterized than...",
      "grantee": "Emory University",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "Emory University",
      "topics": [
        "Enteric Diseases and Diarrhea",
        "Vaccine Delivery",
        "Vaccine Development"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1163272",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 13000,
      "categories": [
        "US Program"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-08T08:00:00",
      "description": "to support LearnLaunch Across Boundaries Conference",
      "grantee": "LearnLaunch Institute",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "LearnLaunch Institute",
      "topics": [
        "K-12",
        "K-12 Education"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1169222",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 250000,
      "categories": [
        "US Program"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-08T08:00:00",
      "description": "to improve outcomes for English Language Learners in Seattle and South King County",
      "grantee": "OneAmerica",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "OneAmerica",
      "topics": [
        "Community Grants"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1164859",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 85000,
      "categories": [
        "Global Health"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-08T08:00:00",
      "description": "to fund cholera / enteric researchers (travel costs) to attend the 51st US-Japan Cholera Conference that they would otherwise not be able to afford to contribute to.",
      "grantee": "International Vaccine Institute",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "International Vaccine Institute",
      "topics": [
        "Enteric Diseases and Diarrhea"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1168711",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 6000,
      "categories": [
        "Special Projects"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-07T08:00:00",
      "description": "to provide for general operating support",
      "grantee": "Center for US Global Leadership",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "Center for US Global Leadership",
      "topics": [
        "Community Grants"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1167614",
      "year": "2016"
    },
    {
      "amount": 3000000,
      "categories": [
        "US Program"
      ],
      "date": "2016-12-07T08:00:00",
      "description": "to support the Center on Education and the Workforce's research and policy agenda to better align postsecondary education and the workforce, with an emphasis on inequalities in the...",
      "grantee": "Georgetown University",
      "iconUrl": "",
      "languageCode": "en",
      "mediaType": "Grant",
      "regions": [
        ""
      ],
      "subtitle": null,
      "thumbnailAltText": "",
      "thumbnailUrl": "",
      "title": "Georgetown University",
      "topics": [
        "Postsecondary Success"
      ],
      "url": "/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database/Grants/2016/12/OPP1165028",
      "year": "2016"
    }
  ],
  "facets": [
    {
      "field": "gfocategories",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "US Program",
          "count": 5859
        },
        {
          "name": "Global Development",
          "count": 4441
        },
        {
          "name": "Global Health",
          "count": 3719
        },
        {
          "name": "Communications",
          "count": 1149
        },
        {
          "name": "Global Policy & Advocacy",
          "count": 879
        },
        {
          "name": "Special Projects",
          "count": 465
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "field": "gfotopics",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Community Grants",
          "count": 2393
        },
        {
          "name": "K-12 Education",
          "count": 2007
        },
        {
          "name": "Global Policy & Advocacy",
          "count": 1507
        },
        {
          "name": "Communications",
          "count": 1246
        },
        {
          "name": "Discovery and Translational Sciences",
          "count": 1227
        },
        {
          "name": "Agricultural Development",
          "count": 866
        },
        {
          "name": "K-12",
          "count": 862
        },
        {
          "name": "HIV",
          "count": 690
        },
        {
          "name": "Global Libraries",
          "count": 671
        },
        {
          "name": "Vaccine Delivery",
          "count": 655
        },
        {
          "name": "Postsecondary Success",
          "count": 645
        },
        {
          "name": "Family Health: Family Planning",
          "count": 625
        },
        {
          "name": "Family Health: Nutrition",
          "count": 530
        },
        {
          "name": "Family Health: Maternal, Newborn, and Child Health",
          "count": 433
        },
        {
          "name": "Community Relations",
          "count": 420
        },
        {
          "name": "Vaccine Development",
          "count": 393
        },
        {
          "name": "Not Available",
          "count": 383
        },
        {
          "name": "Malaria",
          "count": 377
        },
        {
          "name": "Water, Sanitation, and Hygiene",
          "count": 374
        },
        {
          "name": "Emergency Response",
          "count": 368
        },
        {
          "name": "Enteric Diseases and Diarrhea",
          "count": 359
        },
        {
          "name": "Family Interest Grants",
          "count": 313
        },
        {
          "name": "Pneumonia",
          "count": 286
        },
        {
          "name": "Nutrition",
          "count": 284
        },
        {
          "name": "Financial Services for the Poor",
          "count": 277
        },
        {
          "name": "Tuberculosis",
          "count": 277
        },
        {
          "name": "Libraries",
          "count": 262
        },
        {
          "name": "Charitable Sector Support",
          "count": 224
        },
        {
          "name": "Pacific Northwest: Family Homelessness",
          "count": 223
        },
        {
          "name": "College Ready",
          "count": 205
        },
        {
          "name": "Research & Development",
          "count": 195
        },
        {
          "name": "Polio",
          "count": 188
        },
        {
          "name": "Pacific Northwest: Early Learning",
          "count": 182
        },
        {
          "name": "Integrated Delivery",
          "count": 172
        },
        {
          "name": "Table Sponsorships",
          "count": 164
        },
        {
          "name": "Integrated Development",
          "count": 119
        },
        {
          "name": "Strategic Partnerships",
          "count": 117
        },
        {
          "name": "India",
          "count": 116
        },
        {
          "name": "Neglected Tropical Diseases",
          "count": 115
        },
        {
          "name": "Africa",
          "count": 89
        },
        {
          "name": "Special Initiatives (Active projects are now part of other strategies)",
          "count": 67
        },
        {
          "name": "Neglected and Infectious Diseases",
          "count": 66
        },
        {
          "name": "China",
          "count": 43
        },
        {
          "name": "Scholarships",
          "count": 39
        },
        {
          "name": "Tobacco",
          "count": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Europe",
          "count": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "Special Initiatives",
          "count": 22
        },
        {
          "name": "Philanthropic Partnerships",
          "count": 17
        },
        {
          "name": "Europe Office",
          "count": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "field": "gfoyear",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "2009 and earlier",
          "count": 6608
        },
        {
          "name": "2015",
          "count": 1652
        },
        {
          "name": "2016",
          "count": 1546
        },
        {
          "name": "2013",
          "count": 1473
        },
        {
          "name": "2014",
          "count": 1472
        },
        {
          "name": "2012",
          "count": 1260
        },
        {
          "name": "2011",
          "count": 1240
        },
        {
          "name": "2010",
          "count": 921
        },
        {
          "name": "2017",
          "count": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "field": "gforegions",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "North America",
          "count": 5817
        },
        {
          "name": "Sub-Saharan Africa",
          "count": 1546
        },
        {
          "name": "Asia",
          "count": 1192
        },
        {
          "name": "Middle East, North Africa, and Greater Arabia",
          "count": 223
        },
        {
          "name": "South America",
          "count": 152
        },
        {
          "name": "Europe",
          "count": 130
        },
        {
          "name": "Central America and the Caribbean",
          "count": 110
        },
        {
          "name": "Australia and Oceania",
          "count": 29
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 16175
}
```

With the built-in `json` module, you could easily extract info you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with [`dryscrape`](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) like so:

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ses = dryscrape.Session()
ses.visit("http://www.gatesfoundation.org/How-We-Work/Quick-Links/Grants-Database#q/page=2")
s = BeautifulSoup(ses.body())
s2 = s.select("table.table.push-bottom")[0]
print s2
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll not be able to use `BeautifulSoup4` as intended, because the page is rendered through JavaScript.

You can either use [dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Dryscrape is more user friendly in my opinion, but is not officially supported on Windows.

Also, check out [avis'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382297/avi) excellent answer regarding this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/1429776

Answer (score 0):

This page is rendered by JavaScript, requests or urllib can not handle the JS, they will only get html code. And as you can see, there is no table.

[image: Disable the JS in your browser]

Use selenium or mimic the requsts of this page.